# Ngx-translate: How to access JSON array value directly in Angular with key reference

Tags: json, angular, ngx-translate

I am doing POC on translating my app using ngx-translate. I will get JSON response from my API url. In that response, can some one help me how to access the JSON array value with out referring array numbers? My JSON response is given below.

```
{
    "Data": {
        "FirstData": [{
                "key": "FirstKey",
                "value": "FirstValue"
            },
            {
                "key": "SecondKey",
                "value": "SecondValue"
            }
        ]
    },
    "IsSuccessful": true,
    "HttpStatusCode": 200,
    "Exception": null
}
```

So, in my view to refer **"FirstValue"**, I have to do something like ( which I dont want to)

```
<h1> {{'Data.FirstData.0.value' | translate }} </h1> <!--First Value -->
```

Here "0" is tightly coupled. Is there any other way by accessing via key?

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the response of your API to contain only the key/value pairs.

This is the desired JSON:

```
{
    "FirstKey": "FirstValue",
    "SecondKey": "SecondValue"
}
```

Then use it like that:

```
<h1> {{'FirstKey' | translate }} </h1>
```

Comment: Thanks Markus. I did the same at last to achieve my POC. Keeping key value pair is as simple rather going on to arrays. Also, I don't see any solution with out using array index for JSON arrray value response.